# Downloading a file from a server and place is a destination folder

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have to add a custom file to a Docker image, in bin folder inside my application folder. File is to be downloaded from a server. I provide host to build command using `--add-host`, as mentioned [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/).

In Dockerfile, I add:

```
ENV APP_HOME = /opt/my-app
ENV FILE_URL = ....
RUN cd ${APP_HOME}/bin/ && { curl -o some-name ${FILE_URL} ; cd -; }
```

During build, I can see download happening, but in container I see file is not present in `${APP_HOME}/bin`.

Is this wrong way of achieving this?

PS: Extra spaces around '=' in ENV definitions were the cause. Removing them solved the issue.

Comment: You need to use copy command as you want to copy the file from one location to another within your container's filesystem

Comment: What else is in the Dockerfile?  Is this part of a multi-stage build, or have you declared a `VOLUME` anywhere?  There are extra spaces in the `ENV` line as you've shown it that potentially cause trouble but I'd expect you to have noticed that in the `docker build` output already (a couple of stray `=` would presumably cause syntax errors).

Comment: Thanks. Extra space turned out to be the culprit, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Docker's `ADD` directive instead of running curl in a RUN directive.

You can download it using the below steps and copy it to the destination folder

```
# Download to /tmp path
ADD <your_file_url> /tmp  

# Copy to the destination folder
cp /tmp/<you_file_name> <your_destination_folder>
```